# Show Focused DIV on Viewport & Hide Unfocused DIVs on Scrolling using Pure Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I am using Pure Vanilla JavaScript to create an HTML form with the same effect as on SurveyMonkey forms like an example at https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Online-Product-Feedback-Survey-Template-new

What I want to achieve is to make my form questions' opacity light and make one on-screen question opacity:0; so that it will be fully visible to get focus from the user and make all other question of that form dim same as an upper example while scrolling up and down.

For that, I tried my code after getting different tips from different resources and here I am sharing it. Check out live working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/894ths7g/)** of my work and edit it there.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="radio" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="radio" name="1" value="No"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="radio" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="radio" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="radio" name="1" value="No"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="radio" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="radio" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="radio" name="1" value="No"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="radio" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="radiomark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="No"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="No"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="questionDIV overlay">
        <h3>Question # 1) Our purpose / vision / mission / values reflect delivering value for all stakeholders...</h3>
        <p><label class="container">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Yes"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">No<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="No"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
        <p><label class="container">Partially<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="Partially"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {opacity:0.2}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Example from https://www.javascripttutorial.net/sample/dom/event/visible-viewport/index.html
function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    );
}

const box = document.querySelector('.questionDIV');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   if (isInViewport(box) ==  true) {
        document.querySelector('.questionDIV').classList.remove("overlay");
   } else {
        document.querySelector('.questionDIV').classList.add("overlay");
   }

}, {
    passive: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Problem lies in your ".questionDIV" selector-method.

document.querySelector only returns the first occurence it finds. All the blocks after the first never get evaluated by "isInViewport".

You need to get a list of all question-containers and iterate over them during the scroll event. Like this:

```
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.questionDIV');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
for(let i = 0; i < box.length;i++){
console.log(box[i]);
console.log(isInViewport(box[i]));
   if (isInViewport(box[i]) ==  true) {
        box[i].classList.remove("overlay");
   } else {
        box[i].classList.add("overlay");
   }
}


}, {
    passive: true
});
```

After that you just need to fine-tune your code to make sure only one question at a time is active. Edited JSFIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pmhyor06/)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake and fixing it. -- Can you make it the same like I want as mentioned in the question means only one (middle one) should be fully visible even 2-3 divs are coming in the viewport. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You will need to define offsets in your "isInViewport"-function and restrict the evaluation to  a fraction of the screen (i edited my fiddle with an static offset example, so you can check that out).

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I will try to make it only show one middle DIV rest hide all.

Comment: Just change the below function to achieve as per the question asked ---

function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= ((window.innerHeight/2)-(el.clientHeight)) &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= ((window.innerHeight/2)+(el.clientHeight)) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth)
    );
}